# Referencing @string with empty "" textView android xml

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-xml, android-resources

new dev here and hoping someone can help me, i have looked and cannot seem to find an answer to my question, i have all my textviews `@strings` but i am wondering, i have a textview that has an empty value in my xml on android studio i.e `android:text=""`, i have to leave this empty as this is to display a results from a string array.

So my question is how can i add this to `@string` values when it is empty?
sorry for the noobish question but i have not been able to find the answer to my question!

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than creating the empty string resource, I'd suggest that if you do not have any default text you can just **remove** `android:text=""`. That means blank.

It is not mandatory to put that property in your xml.

Comment: what about localization if the string is not referenced?

Comment: how will you localize blank? blank is blank in all locales. :)

Comment: if you have it blank in one locale and have some value in another locale then it is good to create `<string name="strName"></string>` for the locales you have blank. (as suggested in other answers). But if all locales have it blank, there is really no need for localization.

Answer (score 24):

A shorter version that does not generate a lint warning for the empty body of the xml tag:

```
<string name="empty" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply define a string like

```
<string name="empty"></string>
```

in your strings.xml file

Comment: would this work for localization as i read that all textviews need to be @string for different countries

Comment: Obviously. The name of the resource doesn't change. And since its value is fixed (not translatable), you only need to set it once, in the (default) `values` folder.

Comment: What about using @null for the value?

Comment: @ChefPharaoh I'd prefer "", since `@null` sounds like something that sets a value to NULL. And NULL != "".

Comment: this notation results in the lint warning, xml tag has empty body. This can be avoided by writing <string name="empty" />

Comment: Well, Lint can be configured to bypass "not so useful" warnings... ;)

Answer (score 0):

XML won't take white space by default it will trim the spaces, So use \u0020 inside string tag instead of blank or white space.

Example : `<string name="whitespace">\u0020</string>`